# Is there a way to ignore compilation error for a JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, compiler-errors

I have to intentially ignore Compilation error in a jsp file.

**What is being implemented?**

for a use-case, i have to override  tag in a service which is defined in other service. We have an in house page assembly logic to achieve it.

**What is the issue?**

I am getting `unterminated form jag` error and i need to ignore this error for my JSP file because my page assembly service will combine this form and send it to client.

```
[jasper] At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
   [jasper] Compilation error
   [jasper] Error count: [1]
```

**What are the things which i tried?**

`<%-- @SuppressWarnings("jasper") --%>`

`<%-- @ignoreCompilationErrors --%>`

`<%@ suppressError jasper="true" %>`

Please let me know if there's a way to suppress error for a particular jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

You can not ignore this kind of compilation error, as JSPs are first compiled into standalone Servlets, which are in turn compiled into binary .class files.

While you can generate unbalanced HTML tags as you please, you absolutely can not do so with JSP-Taglibs: They will *always* need to be balanced *in the same JSP file*.

So, what you can do is separate out by having "outer" tags in one file, and "inner" tags in another (included) one (to a certain extent), but you typically can't separate them into separate beginning & ending.

Another alternative is to separate a JSP out into JSPF or other fragments. If you *statically* include them into a single JSP file *at compile time*, you can spread them out over multiple files. In general, from a maintainability standpoint, I'd *strongly* prefer not to separate beginning and end of a JSP tag though.